# UPDATE statement with and without SELECT keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, update

I have been doing some testing on removing the `SELECT` keyword from this update:

```
Update  #tmpDriverTime
Set     WorkDay2 = (Select IsNull(Sum(PyblHrs),0)
From    spr_DriverTimeEntry
Where   spr_DriverTimeEntry.DrvrID = #tmpDriverTime.EmployeeNo
And     Convert(Varchar(12),dtwrkd,112) = Convert(Varchar(12),@StartDate_1,112))
```

From the testing I have done it looks like the same data is returned whether or not I have the `SELECT` keyword. I ran the code by our DBA to get his approval of removing the `SELECT` statement and he said I can not as removing the `SELECT` statement would cause the update to work differently but he can not articulate how it works differently. I have done some searching on the new and found a few MSDN pages where they run the `UPDATE FROM` command with out a `SELECT` keyword. So now I am confused, my testing and other examples I found on MSDN say I can remove the `SELECT` keyword but my DBA says no. Does the removal of the `SELECT` keyword affect how the `UPDATE FROM` works and if so how does it affect it?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis in your code.  That missing parenthesis, depending on where it *should* be, could mean two very different answers.

Comment: Missed the last paren in the copy/past. Added it in.

Comment: If all you remove is the SELECT keyword, that should fail with a syntax error. Can you post *both* statements you are running so we can compare them ourselves? Also, can you give us a hint about what tables contain the columns `PyblHrs` and `dtwrkd`? We tend to use table aliases so that nobody has to have intimate knowledge of the schema to understand which table a column comes from...

Comment: This is not an `UPDATE...FROM` statement. The `FROM` is a part of the (correlated) subquery, the `SELECT`. That is, your UPDATE statement has this form: `UPDATE table SET column = (SELECT ... FROM ...)`, **not** this one: `UPDATE table SET column = (SELECT ...) FROM ...`. In the latter case, the `SELECT` could indeed be omitted if it was just `(SELECT scalar_expression)`. (Unless the expression included aggregate functions, but in case of `(SELECT scalar_expression)` using those wouldn't make much sense = unlikely.)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would re-write this in the following way, to clearly separate the source and the target, instead of using this subquery assignment technique. I am making assumptions on where some of these columns are coming from, of course, because you didn't use aliases, so the references were ambiguous.

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME;
SET @sd = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate_1), 0);

;WITH hrs(DrvrID, ph) AS 
(
  SELECT EmployeeNo, SUM(PyblHrs)
    FROM #tmpDriverTime
    GROUP BY EmployeeNo
)
UPDATE e
  -- "WorkDay2" represents a sum of payable hours? Quaint.
  SET WorkDay2 = COALESCE(hrs.ph, 0)
  FROM hrs
  INNER JOIN dbo.spr_DriverTimeEntry AS e -- schema prefix always, please
  ON hrs.DrvrID = e.DrvrID
  -- please don't convert both sides to a string
  -- use a range, then you can still use an index:
  WHERE e.dtwrkd >= @sd
    AND e.dtwrkd <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @sd);
```